# The syscall __NR_perf_event_open seems doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, perf

I want to use the syscall of __NR_perf_event_open for my Android app.

The code runs normally on linux but does not work on Android.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

long perf_event_open( struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                  int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags )
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall( __NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
               group_fd, flags );
    return ret;
}
int main() {
//In the main function, I call perf_event_open:
 struct perf_event_attr pe;
 int fd;
 fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
 ...
}
```

However, the fd always return the value -1. When I use "errno.h", it gave the error informaiton of:EBADF：bad file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

you have not configured  "struct perf_event_attr pe;"  yet

Answer (score 0):

because pid == -1 and cpu == -1 is not valid. you can check it in http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html

Comment: int perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *attr, pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags); 

thus

   fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0)

pid = 0 cpu = -1 which is valid combination.

But even 
    perf_event_open(&pe, /*pid*/0, /*cpu*/-1, /group_id*/-1, PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP); 
returns errno=9 "Bad file number" :(